# Working with recursive anonymous blocks in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I love JavaScript's ability to define functions as variables and am trying to do something similar in Objective-C. In particular, I want to write a recursive function using an anonymous block that I can call on an object and have it work its way through a tree, applying a change at each node:

```
void ( ^setDetailsLoaded )( Product* ) = ^void ( Product* prod ) {
    prod.detailsLoaded = true;
    for ( Group* group in prod.groups ) {
        for ( Product* mod in group.mods )
            setDetailsLoaded( mod );
    }
};
setDetailsLoaded( product ); <-- error here
```

However, I'm getting the strange error `error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file`[sic] when I run the program (which compiles fine).

I'm just wondering if perhaps I need to retain the block or something, or if I should just do this with function pointers instead of blocks.

Comment: Make the block itself a `__block` variable to capture it by reference instead of by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way blocks are implemented—they make a const copy of all primitive type variables, and a strong reference to all object type variables referenced in them at creation time—attempting to recursively reference a block within itself will result in the crash that you saw.

You can solve this by using the `__block` annotation on the block variable itself:

```
__block void ( ^setDetailsLoaded )( Product* ) = ^void ( Product* prod ) {
    prod.detailsLoaded = true;
    for ( Group* group in prod.groups ) {
        for ( Product* mod in group.mods )
            setDetailsLoaded( mod );
    }
};
```

See [@bbum's blog post on blocks](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/) for more details (specifically tip #7).

Comment: That is indeed it! Thank you--I will read up on the `__block` annotation.

Comment: "they copy all the variables referenced in them to the heap at creation time" No. They copy the values of all the variables referenced into the block at creation time. At creation time the block is still on the stack.

Comment: @newacct You're right, I screwed that one up. I've edited my response to hopefully be less misleading.

Comment: I still get `Capturing setDetailsLoaded strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle.`

Comment: That's expected and follows directly from frozendevil's answer. The block references itself, ARC sees the block as an object type and accordingly creates a strong reference to the block from within the block. You can get around this with some pointer magic.

typedef void(^TestBlock)(NSObject *);

        __block TestBlock theBlock;
        const __block TestBlock *blockPtr = &theBlock;
        theBlock = ^void ( NSObject* prod ) {

            if (blockPtr) ((TestBlock)(*blockPtr))(nil);